# Android Emulator Shell Redirection

Tags: android, shell, sockets, emulation, qemu

I am trying to redirect the shell of the android emulator to a unix domain socket at boot time.

Unfortunately, the redirection commands I figured out from https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html are not working for me.

**-show-kernel**

With the command

`emulator -avd "AVD_for_Nexus_4" -no-window -show-kernel -verbose -no-boot-anim -qemu ...`

therefore with "-show-kernel" included I get a shell on stdin.

**-shell-serial**

If I try to redirect the shell with the command:

`emulator -avd "AVD_for_Nexus_4" -no-window -shell-serial unix:/tmp/avd1.sock,server -verbose -no-boot-anim -qemu ...`

and access the unix domain socket via `nc -U /tmp/avd1.sock`
I neither get a shell nor the kernel log.

**-show-kernel and -shell-serial**

With -show-kernel and -shell-serial I can at least access the kernel logs on the socket:

`emulator -avd "AVD_for_Nexus_4" -no-window -show-kernel -shell-serial unix:/tmp/avd1.sock,server -verbose -no-boot-anim -qemu ...`

**shell-serial stdio**

Interestingly, with

`emulator -avd "AVD_for_Nexus_4" -no-window -shell-serial stdio -verbose -no-boot-anim  -qemu ...`

there is no shell at all.

Now I want to have both the kernel logs and the shell on the unix domain socket.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Any ideas? Or is there a better place to ask this question?